# Find out whether a polynomial is irreducible or not

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f=X^7-(7-6i)X^3+5X^2+3+6i\in\mathbb{Z}[i][X]$. Check whether $f$ is irreducible:

- over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$
- over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Probably I will have to use Einstein criterion with some substitution, but I have problems with notation: what do $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ mean?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[i]=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ is the ring of  Gaussian integers. Hint: We have the factorization into primes $5=(2+i)(2-i)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Just from looking at the norms it seems possible that one of those primes is a factor of all the coefficients.

Comment: What about $Q(i)$ please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(1+4i)&(1+2i)=-7+6i\\
(1-2i)&(1+2i)=5\\
3&(1+2i)=3+6i
\end{align}$$
Now $1+2i$ doesn't divide $3$ as $|1+2i|=5>3$ and
$$
(a+ib)(c+id)=(1+2i)\implies(ac-bd,bc+ad)=(1,2)\implies (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=5\implies a^2+b^2=1, c^2+d^2=5\;(\text{WLOG})\implies a+ib=\pm1,\pm i
$$
So $a+ib$ [is a unit in](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Units_of_Gaussian_Integers) $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $1+2i$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. So applying Eisenstein's criterion we see $f$ is indeed irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: What about $Q(i)$ please?

Comment: Gauss' lemma takes care of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)   But is integer=gaussian integer too?

Comment: Yes, Gauss' Lemma works if you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.